# Xcode can't see swift subclass

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiscrollview

I subclassed UIScrollView to add some functionality with regards to scrolling and buttons, and Xcode is incapable of seeing my subclass for whatever reason.

```
let scrollView = CustomScrollView()
```

just throws me a "use of unresolved identifier 'CustomScrollView'" error. I've cleaned the project, restarted Xcode, and the class is definitely added to my project target, so I'm not too sure what's going on. Here's all of the code in the CustomScrollView class:

```
import UIKit

class CustomScrollView: UIScrollView {

  override func touchesShouldBegin(touches: NSSet!,
    withEvent event: UIEvent!,
    inContentView view: UIView!) -> Bool
  {
    if (view .isKindOfClass(UIButton))
    {
      return true
    }

    else
    {
      return super.touchesShouldCancelInContentView(view)
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Things to check:

1. File is included in the target. (You indicate this is done.)
2. Make sure it is in the same module. (Or try making it public.)
3. The compilation of the file with the class succeeds.

Have you tried accessing it from within the file it is declared in?

Comment: everything you mentioned was as it should be, I ended up removing it from the target and then readding it and then it worked... just one of those weird things I guess

Comment: I'll leave the answer as it might help someone else. Not seen Xcode do that before but I have seen similar things in Interface Builder where moving something and moving it back restores proper behaviour so I'm not completely shocked.

Answer (score 0):

I was going in circles for a while trying to solve a similar problem myself.

I had created a class and somehow saved it inside Base.lproj. For this project I hadn't actually created any other files there so I don't know why it switched to saving there (but I might've been around Base.lproj on a different project).

Moving the source back in to the main folder, adding back to the project, and then to the target made everything work again.